# Python "'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'" error

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a python code below which defines a function which returns the scrabble score of the string given to it:

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
             "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
             "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
             "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
             "x": 8, "z": 10}

def scrabble_score(word):
    word1 = (word).lower
    list_a = []
    list_b = range(len(word))
    for i in list_b:
        list_a[i] = word1[i]
    total = 0 
    for i in list_a:
        score  = int(score[i])
        total += score
    return str(total)
```

What's wrong in the code above? The error I get is:
'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: Did you mean to call the method: `word.lower()` instead of `(word).lower`?

Comment: alecxe, I did what you said, but now I get the error "list assignment index out of range". What should I do?

Comment: @S.C. That's because your list_a is empty and you're trying to access the i'th (0,1,2,3, etc.) element. Replace `list_a[i] = word1[i]` with `list_a.append(word1[i])`

Comment: pushkin, I did what you said but now I have a third error " "local variable 'score' referenced before assignment". What should I do?

Comment: @S.C. Notice that you have two variables called `score`. One is global, and one is local. When you do `score = int(score[i])`, the compiler gets confused. Give them different names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__getitem__` is called when you use `[]` to access an element.

When you do `word1 = (word).lower`, you are assigning `word1` to the function `lower`. Rather, you should be calling the function (i.e. `word.lower()`).

When Python sees `word1[i]`, it tries to access the element at the i'th index, but since `word1` is a function instead of a string, Python gets confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
         "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
         "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
         "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
         "x": 8, "z": 10}

def scrabble_score (word):

    word=word.lower()

    total=0
    for char in word:
       if char in score:
        total =total+ score[char]
    return total    

print (scrabble_score('xenophobia') )
```

Comment: Hi Ashraf and welcome to the site! It would be great if you could add a bit of explanation to your answer and maybe reformat the code to be more readable. You can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) about formatting with Markdown.